# Users not able to upgrade or install my Windows Phone App

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone App called Dimensions Weather and News [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=9b98f81f-0b33-4075-bae0-9030177fc20f). Last when I updated My Application to version 1.2.0.0, some users are reporting that they are neither able to install the app nor update the app. The app downloads but then fails during installation. What can be the possible cause of this issue? Is there something wrong with my XAP or configuration?

> Please note that all was working fine until I updated it to the latest version.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do they have 8.1 or just 8.0?

Comment: The issue is sure to occur on WP 8.1. I can't say about Windows Phone 8 as I don't own any device myself.

Comment: The same experience happened to me which left me with several 1-star reviews. Do NOT support ARM. I have always had user experience issues with that platform. Attempt to run your app in airplane mode or simulate a slow connection. Refactor your bootstrap logic accordingly based on the user experience of those states.

Comment: My app uses continuous Internet connection and I have handled all exceptions. `It was all fine` until I added a small button that does nothing much on one of my pages. If you have a device, please try downloading the app and see the issue closely.

Comment: The problem occurs with the 8.1 version (Silverlight I suppose) of your app?

Comment: Any solution suggested?

Comment: @fillobotto, I guess you are right.

Comment: Then check wheter in the app manifest you allowed installation on SD card. If not, then allow it, since MS handled the thing in a very bad way so that, not allowing it, it seems a problem with storie download. There is no prompt message which tell users they can't install it because of SD.

Comment: I remember not allowing installation on Sd cards. I will try undoing it and will let you know.